# Rails3 editing single join table record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, join

User and Building have a has_many relationship through Buildingusers.

Editing user attributes involves editing join table attributes.  However they need to be edited individually, on the basis of the invoked building, for security reasons.  Thus if the user_controller calls the relevant joint table record

```
@buildinguser = Buildinguser.where(['building_id = ? and user_id = ?', session[:building_id], params[:id]]).first
```

The user model states

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :buildingusers, :allow_destroy => true
attr_accessible :buildingusers_attributes
```

How can this be edited in the user form?

```
<%= f.fields_for :buildingusers do |ff| %>
```

generates ALL join table records, which is not the goal

```
<%= f.fields_for @buildinguser do |ff| %>
```

will generate a form, but with incorrect data (id of join table not invoked)

```
<input checked="checked" id="user_buildinguser_operator" name="user[buildinguser][operator]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

The same occurs if the controller and view is invoked via @buildingusers

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "buildinguser[building_id]", session[:building_id] %>
```

did the trick.  Inspired from
[avoiding fields_for adding record to associated model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191067/avoiding-fields-for-for-adding-a-single-record-to-associated-model)